# Spring boot + Hibernate - User is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have seen a lot of topics on Google related to hibernate error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from <model_name>]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from <model_name>]
```

However, none of them help me to solve this issue in my Spring Boot application.

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Take a look on my files:

**DatabaseConfig.java:**

```
package pl.test.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Contains database configurations.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {



    // ------------------------
    // PRIVATE FIELDS
    // ------------------------

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;


    // ------------------------
    // PUBLIC METHODS
    // ------------------------

    /**
     * DataSource definition for database connection. Settings are read from
     * the application.properties file (using the env object).
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Declare the JPA entity manager factory.
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

        // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

        // Vendor adapter
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        // Hibernate properties
        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put(
                "hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        additionalProperties.put(
                "hibernate.show_sql",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        additionalProperties.put(
                "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Declare the transaction manager.
     */
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager =
                new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                entityManagerFactory.getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor is a bean post processor
     * which adds an advisor to any bean annotated with Repository so that any
     * platform-specific exceptions are caught and then rethrown as one
     * Spring's unchecked data access exceptions (i.e. a subclass of
     * DataAccessException).
     */
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
} // class DatabaseConfig
```

---

**User:**

```
package pl.test.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public User() { }

    public User(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

---

**UserDAO:**

```
package pl.test.model.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import pl.test.model.User;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void create(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
        return;
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        if (entityManager.contains(user))
            entityManager.remove(user);
        else
            entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(user));
        return;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List getAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from User").getResultList();
    }

}
```

---

**SampleWebJspApplication:**

```
package pl.test.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleWebJspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

**WelcomeController:**

```
package pl.test.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import pl.test.model.dao.UserDAO;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by zarebaa on 28/11/2015.
 */
@Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pl.test.model")
public class WelcomeController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Value("${application.message:Hello World}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        userDAO.getAll();
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

---

**application.properties:**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
application.message=Hello Phil


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=h2
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

security.basic.enabled=false
security.user.password=password
logging.level.org.springframework.security=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AuditListener=DEBUG

entitymanager.packagesToScan=pl.test.model
```

---

**welcome.jsp:**

### test

**Piece of pom.xml:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <bootstrap.version>3.3.5</bootstrap.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.190</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

I'm getting following error:

```
2015-11-29 17:28:50.862  INFO 9640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
2015-11-29 17:28:51.009 ERROR 9640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw e
xception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not
 mapped [from User]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User]] with root cause

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.j
ar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:293) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2
.3.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at pl.test.model.dao.UserDAO.getAll(UserDAO.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
        at pl.test.model.dao.UserDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5e7d5fdc.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3
.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:654) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at pl.test.model.dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d5ea102.getAll(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at pl.test.web.WelcomeController.welcome(WelcomeController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.
jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEAS
E.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:207) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Do you understand why and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Did you add `User` class to `hibernate.cfg.xml` file?

Comment: No, I don't have to use `hibernate.cfg.xml` file with Spring Boot configuration

Comment: Put your SampleWebJspApplication.java in pl.test package and try to execute the application

Comment: Wow, it helped. Could you please explain why I needed move `SampleWebJspApplication` to `pl.test` package? Also, please let me know what I should do in addition to do not move this file to another package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your `SampleWebJspApplication.java` in `pl.test` package and execute the application.

It is recommended by [Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) to run your application from the root package and all your entities, controllers,DAO's and other service classes should be placed in child packages. This is not a hard and fast rule but it ensures all your subpackage annotated classes are scanned properly

In your case your `User` class is not scanned and `Hibernate` is not able to find the mapping for the same and eventually throwing the `QuerySyntaxException` when executing the `from User` query.

Currently Spring Boot will scan `@Entity` classes if they are placed in the same package or sub-packages where you specified the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. Atleast, this is what I observed while developing spring boot apps lately.

If you do not  want to move the location of the `SampleWebJspApplication.java`, then use `@EntityScan(basePackages = "pl.test.model")`  annotation and this will fix the issue.

Spring Boot Docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html