# Batch processing data from JPA using spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Hey I'm new to spring and I'm trying to do a program that processes a bunch of records from a database and does something to them. Basically gets all records that are in a certain state, run a command in the OS (one per each record), change something in those records.

I figured that the ideal tool for that is using the batch service support of spring. I already had the records that I wanted to read mapped to a JPA bean (Schedule) and I had CrudRepository (ScheduleRepository) so I figured it would be pretty easy to wire everything together, though I didn't know how.

I tried following the [batch service guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) making some adaptations to read the input from JPA. But when I tried to run I got a NullPointerException when spring tries to instantiate JpaPagingItemReader.

I'll try to attach the code that I find most relevant to the question:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    //@Autowired
    //public ScheduleRepository repository;
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Bean
    public Job synchronizeProcess(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("synchronizeProcess")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    private Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Schedule, Schedule> chunk(10)
                .reader(new JpaPagingItemReader<Schedule>())
                .processor(new ScheduleExectutor())
                .writer(new JpaItemWriter<Schedule>())
                .build();
    }
}
```

The application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

Here's the full log:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building runner 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ runner >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ runner ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ runner ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ runner ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/msl09/unsynced/workspace/syncweb_scheduler/runner/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ runner ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ runner <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ runner ---

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-06-06 12:40:55.492  INFO 21085 --- [           main] b.j.t.syncweb.runner.RunnerApplication   : Starting RunnerApplication on myhost-debian with PID 21085 (/home/msl09/unsynced/workspace/syncweb_scheduler/runner/target/classes started by msl09 in /home/msl09/unsynced/workspace/syncweb_scheduler/runner)
2017-06-06 12:40:55.494  INFO 21085 --- [           main] b.j.t.syncweb.runner.RunnerApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-06 12:40:55.533  INFO 21085 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d488830: startup date [Tue Jun 06 12:40:55 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-06 12:40:55.957  WARN 21085 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-06-06 12:40:55.966  WARN 21085 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-06-06 12:40:56.326  INFO 21085 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-06 12:40:56.340  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2017-06-06 12:40:56.385  INFO 21085 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-06-06 12:40:56.386  INFO 21085 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-06 12:40:56.387  INFO 21085 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-06 12:40:56.431  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-06 12:40:56.501  INFO 21085 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2017-06-06 12:40:56.621  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-06-06 12:40:56.622  INFO 21085 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@c3133ad
2017-06-06 12:40:56.809  INFO 21085 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-06 12:40:57.031  WARN 21085 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer       : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs
2017-06-06 12:40:57.032  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: POSTGRES
2017-06-06 12:40:57.151  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2017-06-06 12:40:57.164  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql]
2017-06-06 12:40:57.964  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql] in 800 ms.
2017-06-06 12:40:58.098  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-06 12:40:58.109  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2017-06-06 12:40:58.214  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=synchronizeProcess]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2017-06-06 12:40:58.238  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2017-06-06 12:40:58.251 ERROR 21085 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step step1 in job synchronizeProcess

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at br.jus.tjse.syncweb.runner.RunnerApplication.main(RunnerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doOpen(JpaPagingItemReader.java:177) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 41 common frames omitted

2017-06-06 12:40:58.264 ERROR 21085 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Exception while closing step execution resources in step step1 in job synchronizeProcess

org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:136) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:85) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:305) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at br.jus.tjse.syncweb.runner.RunnerApplication.main(RunnerApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doClose(JpaPagingItemReader.java:236) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.close(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:133) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
        ... 41 common frames omitted

2017-06-06 12:40:58.305  INFO 21085 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=synchronizeProcess]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [FAILED]
2017-06-06 12:40:58.307  INFO 21085 --- [           main] b.j.t.syncweb.runner.RunnerApplication   : Started RunnerApplication in 3.142 seconds (JVM running for 5.223)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.444 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-06T12:40:58-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/351M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-06 12:40:58.478  INFO 21085 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4d488830: startup date [Tue Jun 06 12:40:55 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-06 12:40:58.479  INFO 21085 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-06-06 12:40:58.480  INFO 21085 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

What's the correct way to instantiate the JpaPaginItemReader?

Comment: Not really enough info here -- stack trace perhaps, where are you in the tutorial?

Comment: You need to define it as a `@Bean` and inject the `EntityManagerFactory` and you obviously need to tell it which query to execute to get your items. The same applies for the writer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@M. Deinum thanks a bunch, using your tip I was able to figure how to map fix that bug. Here is how my configuration class is now:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job synchronizeProcess(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("synchronizeProcess")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Schedule, Schedule> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(new ScheduleExectutor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaItemWriter<Schedule> writer() {
        JpaItemWriter<Schedule> jpaItemWriter = new JpaItemWriter<>();
        jpaItemWriter.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return jpaItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Schedule> reader() {
        JpaPagingItemReader<Schedule> jpaPagingItemReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Schedule>();
        jpaPagingItemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        jpaPagingItemReader.setQueryString("SELECT s FROM Schedule s WHERE s.status = 'WAITING'");
        jpaPagingItemReader.setPageSize(10);
        return jpaPagingItemReader;
    }

}
```

Now hibernate s complaining that Schedule is not mapped but at least that's a different error and I think that's more related to me not knowing how JPQL works.

Comment: That last problem that I have mentioned was because spring did not scan my data package (where the beans are located). The solution used was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985306/spring-boot-hibernate-user-is-not-mapped